# Calling function from Julia file does not read image in Python file

Tags: python, image, julia

In Julia I have built a function that changes an image a little bit. The function takes in as input following type

```
Matrix{RGB{N0f8}} (alias for Array{RGB{Normed{UInt8, 8}}, 2})
```

I have created environment where I use Julia and Python. So in Python I want to test function on the cifar database. I want to change the images in the cifar database with my function.
But whenever I try to run the function from Julia on images in the Python file, I get this error:

```
JULIA: BoundsError: attempt to access 100×100×3 Array{Float32, 3} at index [1, 1]
```

Even through if I try to access this coordinates directly like this in Python:

```
image[1, 1]
```

it is completely fine and gives me the rgb values. So I was curious maybe there is some function from images that I could apply?

Comment: you need to show some minimal code. Basically images are 3-dimensional objects (because there are 3 values for colors). Perhaps you are doing (intentionally) some type conversion between Julia and Python and `Matrix{RGB}` ends up to be a 3d Python numpy object (or the other way around). Could you make a minimalistic code (perhaps image with 4 pixels) to replicate this error?

Answer (score 0):

> 100×100×3 Array{Float32, 3} at index [1, 1]

you need 3 numbers to index a single element of this 3D array. If I have to guess, I would think the `R` pixel of the `image[1, 1]` in Python would be `image[1, 1, 1]` in Julia, and the `G` pixel is `image[1, 1, 2]`, and the `B` pixel is `image[1, 1, 3]`

---

looking at this example: https://juliaimages.org/latest/tutorials/arrays_colors/#fixedpoint

I think given a 3D array, you can convert it to an RGB matrix by using this from `Images.jl`:

```
using Images

img = colorview(RGB, reshape(image, (3, 100, 100)))
```